# Show in Woocommerce admin orders list the username that has completed the order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

In woocommerce how to show in admin order list which user has mark as "completed" 
 the order like in this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the following… But it will be generated for the orders which status has been changed to completed after starting when you will add this code:

```
// Save backend user and time for completion order
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'user_has_completed_order');
function user_has_completed_order( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) return;

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    if ( ! empty( $user_id ) && $user_id != 0 ) {
        $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_completed_by_user', $user_id );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_completed_datetime', $now );
    }
}

// Adding 1 new columns to backend order list
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_shop_order_column',11);
function custom_shop_order_column($columns)
{
    $reordered_columns = array();

    // Woocommerce version 3.3+ compatibility
    $location_after = version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.3', '<' ) ? 'order_notes' : 'order_status';

    // Inserting the new column in a specific location
    foreach( $columns as $key => $column){
        $reordered_columns[$key] = $column;
        if( $key == $location_after ){
            $reordered_columns['completed_by'] = __( 'Completed by','woocommerce');
        }
    }
    return $reordered_columns;
}

// Adding the data for the additional column (example)
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_orders_list_column_content', 10, 2 );
function custom_orders_list_column_content( $column, $post_id )
{
    if( 'completed_by' == $column )
    {
        // Get custom post meta data
        $user_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_completed_by_user', true );
        $date_time = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_completed_datetime', true );
        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date_time));
        if( ! empty($user_id) ){
            $user_data = get_userdata( $user_id );
            $user_url = get_edit_user_link( $user_id );
            echo '<a href="'.$user_url.'" title="'.$date_time.'">'.$user_data->user_login.'</a>';
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

It works as well in all woocommerce versions included last version 3.3 where order list has been slightly improved:

[image]

Comment: Okay man... sorry for asking where i have to put his code functions.php ? can u tell me a little bit if this isnt a problem

Comment: @X-Developer As you can see below the answer code: *"Code goes **in function.php file of your active child theme** (or active theme)…"*, so yes function.php file is the right place.